# Compute this fractal matrix

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, fractal

The unique-disjointness matrix ( UDISJ(n) ) is a matrix on all pairs of subsets of `{1...,n}` with entries $$ U_{(A,B)}=\begin{cases}
0, ~ if ~ |A\cap B|=1\\
1, ~ otherwise
\end{cases} $$

Or a bit less mathematical, it is the 2<sup>n</sup> times 2<sup>n</sup> matrix with a `0` in all entries where both indices have exactly one common `1` bit in their binary representation and a `1` in all other entries.

### Example:

```
      0   1  10  11  100 101 110 111
     _______________________________
0   | 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   | 1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
10  | 1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
11  | 1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
100 | 1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
101 | 1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
110 | 1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
111 | 1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1
```

Write a program or function that takes an integer `n` as input and outputs the corresponding \$2^n \times 2^n\$ matrix.

Rules:

- The values in the matrix can either be 0 / 1 (as numbers) or truthy/falsey
- You are **not** allowed to permute the rows/columns of the matrix
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest solution (per language) wins
- Your solution only needs to handle `n` between `2` and `10` (inclusive)

First 4 elements:

```
n=1:
1 1
1  

n=2:

1 1 1 1
1   1  
1 1    
1     1

n=3:

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1   1   1   1  
1 1     1 1    
1     1 1     1
1 1 1 1  
1   1     1   1     
1 1         1 1
1     1   1 1 1

n=4:
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
1 1     1 1     1 1     1 1     
1     1 1     1 1     1 1     1 
1 1 1 1         1 1 1 1         
1   1     1   1 1   1     1   1 
1 1         1 1 1 1         1 1 
1     1   1 1 1 1     1   1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1                 
1   1   1   1     1   1   1   1 
1 1     1 1         1 1     1 1 
1     1 1     1   1 1 1   1 1 1 
1 1 1 1                 1 1 1 1 
1   1     1   1   1   1 1 1 1 1 
1 1         1 1     1 1 1 1 1 1 
1     1   1 1 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 72 bytes

```python
lambda m:(q:=range(2**m))and(((i&j).bit_count()!=1for i in q)for j in q)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3PXISc5NSEhVyrTQKrWyLEvPSUzWMtLRyNTUT81I0NDQy1bI09ZIyS-KT80vzSjQ0FW0N0_KLFDIVMvMUCjVBzCwIE2re64KiTKA69Zg8db2s_Mw8DXUFOMNQPTorFq4lUxNuUJqGoaamJhd5Wo3I12pMvlYToFaIlxcsgNAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
o<ÝDδ&b1ö≠
```

Outputs as a matrix with `1`s and `0`s.

Port of [*@mousetail*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263366/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/3@bwXJdzW9SSDA9ve9S54P9/YwA) or [verify the first 5 test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/qquSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkX1oC4/3Ptzk81@XcFrUkw8PbHnUu@G/LpRRQlFpSUqlbUJSZV5KaopAPU61zaLfB4Q1WOoe22f8HAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
o           # Push 2 to the power the (implicit) input-list
 <Ý         # Pop and push a list in the range [0,2**input)
   Dδ&      # Create a bitwise-AND table of it:
   D        #  Duplicate the list
    δ       #  Pop both lists and apply double-vectorized:
     &      #   Bitwise-AND
      b     # Then convert each inner value to a binary-string
       1ö   # Vectorized-sum its digits by converting from base-1 to a base-10 integer
         ≠  # Check for each that it's NOT equal to 1 (0 if 1; 1 otherwise)
            # (after which the matrix is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Not again... Porting now lol

Comment: @TheThonnu Haha, déjà vu. ;)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
2ṗ«'`§’n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4c7ph1arJxxa/qhhZt7///9NAA)

```
            (input: n)
2ṗ          nth Cartesian power of [1, 2]: for example,
              [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,2], [1,1,2,1], ..., [2,2,2,2]] if n=4
  «'`       self-table by vectorized minimum
     §      sum each vector
      ’     subtract 1
       n    not equal to… (implicit argument: n)
```

Instead of `0b0011 & 0b0110 = 0b0010` we do `1,1,2,2 « 1,2,2,1 = 1,1,2,1`.

Instead of checking popcount ≠ 1, we check sum ≠ n+1. `§’n` is shorter than `’§n1`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 66 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.25 bytes

```
Eʁ:v⋏bvṠċ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiRcqBOnbii49iduG5oMSLIiwi4oGLXFwwXFwgViIsIjMiXQ==)

*-4.75 bytes thanks to TheThonnu*

The footer formats the resulting matrix into a nice grid like the test cases. Remove it for just a list of lists. Outputs inverted numbers (0s for 1s and 1s for 0s).

I somehow managed to generate like 3 other fractals while solving this, including an upside down triangle thing with the bottom off-center.

### Explained

```
EDẊ‹sƛƒ⋏bT₃;ẇ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ED             # ‎⁡Push three copies of n ** 2
  Ẋ            # ‎⁢Cartesian product of the range [1, n ** 2] and [1, n ** 2]
   ‹           # ‎⁣with all sublists decremented
    s          # ‎⁤and sorted
     ƛ     ;   # ‎⁢⁡To each pair
      ƒ⋏       # ‎⁢⁢  reduce by bitwise and
        bT₃    # ‎⁢⁣  is the length of truthy indices 1?
            ẇ  # ‎⁢⁤wrap into 2 ** n chunks
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [9 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJFyoE6duKLj2J24bmgxIsiLCLigYtcXDBcXCBWIiwiMyJd) (or 8.25 with Vyncode)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
2RẉDȷỌ€ʂ⁻Q
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPTJSJUUxJUJBJTg5RCVDOCVCNyVFMSVCQiU4QyVFMiU4MiVBQyVDQSU4MiVFMiU4MSVCQlEmZm9vdGVyPSVDNCVCMSVDMyVCMGolM0IlQzYlOUQnMCVDMyVCMHYmaW5wdXQ9MyZmbGFncz0=)

Outputs a nested list. The footer formats it into the grid. Port of Lynn's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
2RẉDȷỌ€ʂ⁻Q  # Implicit input
2Rẉ         # [1,2] to the cartesian power of the input
   DȷỌ      # Outer product over minimum with itself
      €ʂ    # Sum each inner list
        ⁻Q  # Decrement, not equal to the input?
            # Implicit output
```

Old:

```python
OLDȷÆ&ıḃ1ȷcḅ  # Implicit input
OL            # Push [0..2**n)
  DȷÆ&        # Outer product over bitwise AND
      ıḃ1ȷc   # Popcount of each
           ḅ  # Equals one?
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes

```python
lambda m:(q:=range(2**m))and[[(n:=i&j)>n^n-1for i in q]for j in q]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXISc5NSEhVyrTQKrWyLEvPSUzWMtLRyNTUT81KiozXyrGwz1bI07fLi8nQN0_KLFDIVMvMUCmNBzCwIE2pSFEgoDyQUbahjpGOsYxJrxcVZUJSZV6KhHpOnrpeVn5mnoa4AZxiqRyfl5-doZGkiTMvUhNuRppGnqakN0qkJsWHBAggNAA)

[mousetail's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263366/20260), but with bit operations instead of `bit_count`. We want to check that `i&j` (which we call `n`) doesn't have exactly one set bit, which means that it's a not power of two. We do this by checking that `n>n^n-1`, which is processed as `n>n^(n-1)`. Let's check that this works in every case:

- If `n` is a power of two, then `n-1` has disjoint bits set to `n` and so their
  XOR is greater than `n`.
- If `n` is any other positive value, then `n` and `n-1` share the same leading bit, and the XOR cancels this bit making the result smaller than `n`.
- For `n==0`, the result is `0`, the same as `n`.

Annoyingly Python doesn't let us do the walrus assignment `q:=range(2**m)` in the iterable of a list comprehension, so the code has it assigned beforehand. loopy walt points out a better way to handle the two levels of iteration is using the classic [divmod two-loop trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/41217/20260) together with the classic [zip/iter chunker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184881/20260).

#### 61 bytes

```python
lambda m:zip(*2**m*[((n:=j&j>>m)>n^n-1for j in range(4**m))])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY1NCsIwEIXXeoqszExshdYupJAcxLZCi0YTmkkpdaFXcVMQvZO30WDp6n3w_h7v7jZcPI1PLcvXddDx7iPb2jXHmrn8bjoQqRBOFACUS7uySjlUdKA40b5nlhlifU3nE2S_GGKF08g-2BTsIonSaBtlVb5cdL2hAXhJfGO9IeBshoQXjfctWKzmZYMBTUANhLgOzelhHP_6BQ)

Comment: [-3](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY1BDoIwFETXeoqu7P8VTIouDAG8h4AJRItt6C8huNCruCExeidvYxoJq3mLmTfPT3cfro7Gl0qL921Q4f57aCtbnytm44fuQERCWJEDUJyalckyixmdKJTK9cwwTayvqLmATJJIWMQSJ83RF8gXchlEwTbYlfFy0fWaBuAF8Y1xmoCzGSTPa-daMFjObo0etUcFhLj2y-lhHP_5Aw) just using the good ol' grouper.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```r
function(n)(y=outer(x<-1:2^n-1,x,bitwAnd))^0-y%in%2^x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw9CoAwDEDh3VMUQUgwBaOb6OA5xA7@FLpEKJXW09e6Pviez1ZNOttHjuBuAUF45/sJl4c0aR57I5op0e5CXORENJ1@GydNb1KWQtVQ2aKq6F244IBa1cS4cvvXjZjKAfMH)

Rather than counting the number of on bits (which is very lengthy in R), tests the equivalent characterization of "equal to a power of 2"; then has to do some reshaping of the vector output of `%in%` to get back to the right shape matrix.

Comment: I cannot find anything on meta - is it generally allowed to output a matrix as a flat vector?

Comment: @pajonk hmm probably not. I didn't notice b/c of the footer, so I'll have to update it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <sup><s>57 54</s></sup> 50 bytes

```arturo
$->n[map^2n'x->map^2n=>[0<>^and dec<=<=and&-1x-1]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?FJPeor)

```
$->n[                     ; a function taking an argument n
    map^2n'x->            ; map over [1..2^n]; assign current elt to x
        map^2n=>[         ; map over [1..2^n]; assign current elt to &
            0<>           ; is zero not equal to
            and&-1x-1     ; bitwise and of current elts minus one
            <=<=          ; duplicated twice
            dec           ; minus one
            and           ; bitwise and
            ^             ; NOS to the TOS power
        ]                 ; end map
]                         ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
mmn1s&VdkQ=^U2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfiflZSbZZ3roKRgqJSd8j83N8@wWC0sJTvQNi7U6P9/EwA)

#### Explanation

```
mmn1s&VdkQ=^U2Q    # implicitly add Q
                   # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
          =^U2Q    # Q = repeated cartesian product of [0,1] Q times
m             Q    # map lambda d over range(Q)
 m       Q         #   map lambda k over range(Q)
     &Vdk          #     d & k, vectorized
    s              #     sum bits
  n1               #     != 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 119 bytes

```
import bitops
proc f(n:int)=
 let r=0..<1 shl n;for i in r:
  var s="";for j in r:s&= $int 1!=popcount i and j
  echo s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BCsIwEEX3PcW3iLQLi10I0prD1NjQKW0mTFI9jJuCeihvYzC4ezx4_P94WprX9b0Esz997jQ7loALBXY-c8IaprAN2VCqDFMfIOpQVecafphgW8MCAllIkwG3TuBVnv_0mLTfKWxjj3qjHDvNS2RCZ68YY9LrgeHT_MsUxzLh_9EX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
2*Ḷ&þ`B§n1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//MirhuLYmw75gQsKnbjH/w4dv4oG2Rylq4oG@wrbCtv//Ng)

### How it works

```
2*Ḷ&þ`B§n1 - Main link. Takes n on the left
2*         - 2 ** n
  Ḷ        - [0, 1, ..., 2**n)
    þ`     - To every pair (a, b) in this range:
   &       -   Bitwise and
      B    - Convert all to binary
       §   - Sums
        n1 - Does not equal 1?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN (CBQN)](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <strike>45 bytes</strike> 22 ‘bytes’

```
{1≠+´¨∧⌜˜⥊∾⌜⍟(-1)˜↕2}
```

I think the following is slightly more elegant, and it's the same number of characters but, alas, more bytes.

```
{1≠+´∘∧⌜˜⥊(↕2)∾⌜⍟⋈⟨⟩}
```

We operate only on bit-strings, rather than integers. `⥊⌜⍟(-1)˜↕2` gives us the list of binary strings of length , which is then anded into a table, and summed: `+´∘∧⌜˜`. We then take only the `1≠` entries.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704qTBvwYKlpSVpuhY3TR81LArOyC-vNnzUuUD70JZDKx51LH_UM-f0nEdLux517AMyH_XO1_gwd-pKXUNNoGjbVKNaY4hmqBkwswA)

Comment: Though I don't know the specifics of why, every BQN answer I've seen here counts 1 glyph as 1 byte. I think you can call these 22 bytes.

Comment: @chunes Thanks, that makes quite a difference!

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>72 56</s> 54 bytes

```ruby
->n{(w=0...1<<n).map{|i|w.map{|j|a=i&j;(a&a-1)**a>0}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BDoIwFAX3nuIlJgQMIhhXaPUgxsUXaCyWlpQ2SChnRwKrN8mbxRj3HmbO5uNdjWHP0iRJsttNRUlD7eiF7zeoPTER1NeQAjpm0eFA93SapnlfkJTgThVWaBXD0reCdrZ1FtSBcC5BxtAAzWGNq7oTJ9lVy6VKcG0aspBCVbB63Ri9sJ9VZRlyrDZLsePPy2tr@fkWvw0HP@CR5UvK/Ac)

This employs one of my favourite bit-twiddling hacks. `a&a-1` gives 0 if `a` has only one bit set. Unfortunately it also gives 0 if `a==0` so we use the fact that any number (including 0) raised to the power 0 is 1 to catch this special case: `(a&a-1)**a`.

So now we have distinction between nonzero and zero numbers. The rules require two distinct values, so we use `>0` to convert to `true/false` and we are done.

The footer in the linked TIO formats the output 2d array line by line, and converts the `true/false` to `1/0`.

Comment: 52 bytes with [Ruby 2.7 Numbered Parameters](https://medium.com/@baweaver/ruby-2-7-numbered-parameters-3f5c06a55fe4) (TIO is stuck on 2.5.5) - [`->n{(w=0...1<<n).map{|i|w.map{a=i&_1;(a&a-1)**a>0}}}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5BisJAFET3nqJACCompgcX4tiZg4wiX01jM7E7dH4Tg8kBPIObgM6h5jYOia7eg6qCuj2c31XtXcn1r2cVLv7mYWIuo1LGURSJ1cqMoxPll1rXZSckdbAVnyMKKBTjyYSSuGma1_Y63FOWQXmzZ23NFEw_Kazn3DOoAOHjAHKOKlgFdj4tZoqyIv2PzAHKuhMxMm1SsO04Ran52FWlwBJdW8YYqO_5pn92rnOce63qCl9iGb8PtW3PJw)

Comment: @ValueInk oh wow thanks, that's new! You really have to check your versions. I still miss when you could write `.5` instead of `0.5`

Comment: CG One Handed pointed it out to me earlier this week and it feels like a whole new world. Also, you can still save a byte on 2.5 by using `j&=i;(j&j-1)**j>0` for 53 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BDoIwFAX3nuIlJkSNIDWukOpBjIsv0NiKLSltkFjOXg2s3iRvFmP9Y4yCx/Siv5uB51mWsbLU2@xN3TfIMCyggkq4PG9UolK23e3UJZ@mKa4ralsIrysnjd7D0auB8a7zDtSDcKxB1tIII@Csb/qDoLZv/peuIYx9k0MrdQNn5t1jkO45q5yhwGzzHCtxO92XlE/o8FlwDCOurPinxB8 "Ruby – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.matrices math.unicode`, 57 bytes

```
[ 2^ dup [ bitand bit-count 1 ≠ ] <matrix-by-indices> ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owU3v0GBPP3crhdzEkgwwoZeUWVKeWZwK4ZTmZSbnp0A5QKIoMzm1WKGgKLWkpLKgKDOvRCE7tSgvNUfBmovLZGlpSZquxU3LaAWjOIWU0gKFaAWgYYl5KSBKNzm_FKjcUOFR5wKFWAUbsGEVukmVupl5KSBT7RRiIQZsSk7MyVEozswtyEnVLUlMyknVg0gsWAChAQ)

```
2^                           ! two to the input power
dup                          ! duplicate
[ ... ] <matrix-by-indices>  ! create an MxN matrix with indices on top of stack
bitand                       ! bitwise and
bit-count                    ! number of on bits
1 ≠                          ! not equal to one
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
oDL<ãε`&b1¢Θ}sô
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//29ETDzDo861YCZiMcKizph9c8O0/8K7McOwOv8z)

Outputs a nested list. The footer formats it into the grid. Port of lyxal's Vyxal answer.

*-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
oDL<ãε`&b1¢Θ}sô  # Implicit input
oD               # Push 2 ** n and duplicate
  L<ã            # Cartesian product of [0..2**n) with itself
     ε      }    # Map over this list:
      `&         #  Bitwise AND of the pair
        b1¢Θ     #  Is the popcount equal to 1?
             sô  # Split into 2 ** n chunks
                 # Implicit output
```

Comment: `Dâ` can be `ã` (and golfing it some more would result in [my 10 bytes answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/263371/52210), which I was already writing before I saw this answer tbh).

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 11 bytes

```
.;`,^2$.@!=1+``@`&@$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWW_SsE3TijFT0HBRtDbUTEhwS1BxUIFJQFYujTWOhTAA)

Returns a matrix with truthy values (positive numbers) for `1` and falsy values (`0`) for `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 52 bytes

```
{(^$_ X+&^$_).rotor($_)».&{!$_||$_!=1+<.msb}}o 1+<*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcxBCsIwFIThq4yPEJIGHhTEhW3u4cpQwYBiTEndlJCTufNiMdbVfIufma/pcahhhfSwNauzcDgZ2UZziq@YVNPnzTLvmqQUztrejByWiy4lormrA3xM6Jn3yFimFSTckYaNHKZZmU7zPd6eikB6i/3v918QodQv)

The version of Raku on TIO fails to parse the `!$_||$_!=1+<.msb` bit, presumably due to a bug, so I've expressed it there as `!($_&&$_==1+<.msb)`, which is equivalent by De Morgan's law, but two bytes longer.

This is an anonymous function consisting of two separate anonymous functions composed together with `o`.  The right-hand function is `1 +< *`, which shifts the number 1 leftwards a number of bits given by its argument; that is, two to the power of the argument.  That number is passed to the left-hand function, where the variable `$_` gets its value.

- `^$_` is a range of numbers from 0 up to one less than `$_`.  For example, when the number passed to the first function is 3, this is the range `0..7`.
- `X+&` gives the cross product of one copy of that range with another using the bitwise-and operator `+&`.
- `.rotor($_)` takes that flat crossed list and makes it into a square matrix.
- `».&{ ... }` recursively applies the code between the braces to each element of that matrix.
- `!$_ || $_ != 1 +< .msb` tests whether each number is zero (`!$_`) or consists of only a single binary digit by comparing the number to 1 bit-shifted left a number of places equal to the number's most significant bit (`1 +< .msb`).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 74 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(1<<n)].map((_,y,a)=>a.map((_,x)=>(g=k=>k?k%2^g(k/2):1)(x&y)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczLDoIwEIXhPU8xG2UmYBXiSmiNz@EtDQKB4pQUYiDGZ0dCdPWdf3Nq/dJd5qq237B95FMhJ5bqLIQ4OadHjNKU6SqeukW8h2OoSSr9z2EOLKWRyhzNKr6VaLYxHSLCYT0S0VRYh03eA4OEXTKTwn4mCAjeHkBmubNNLhpbYoFMy68DqcCJ2laMPvhEv3lhnyCAxcT7TF8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 18 bytes

```
≔Ｘ²ＮθＥθ⭆θ¬⁼¹Σ↨＆ιλ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8jIL88tUjDSEfBM6@gtMSvNDcJyNXU1FEo1LTmCijKzCvR8E0s0CjUUQguAfLSoRy//BIN18LSxJxiDUOgVGmuhlNicaqGU2ZJeWZxqmNeikamjkIO0BgjTQiw/v/f5L9uWQ4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  ²                 Literal integer `2`
 Ｘ                  Raised to power
   Ｎ                Input as a number
≔   θ               Save in variable
      θ             Saved variable
     Ｅ              Map over implicit range
        θ           Saved variable
       ⭆            Map over implicit range and join
               ι    Outer value
              ＆     Bitwise And
                λ   Inner value
             ↨   ²  Convert to base `2`
            Σ       Take the sum
         ¬⁼         Does not equal
           ¹        Literal integer `1`
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 51 bytes

```
n->matrix(2^n,,i,j,sumdigits(bitand(i-1,j-1),2)!=1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LctBCsIwEEDRq4xdzcBkkepClPQoSqSkTKFjSKfgXdwERDyTt1FoV5-3-M9PjkWuQ66vBOG9WHLH715dN0Ur8sD2oszCI8_L1MsgNuNNLGqP4jyPzhO3tAuetpXSvaBCAM9wYMhF1P5uTg2dV2VMqETbUOvaHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language(Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 68 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba8JAFITv@yteV@jFDZLQU@pKFBEsFIrN7fEMS5vEBfNW1oW2iL89bpJLTwPfDDPTmXCqOxPsl@n7puAq12vvzR9unDvXmD7p0hd7DnVb@61tbbjixoY1f@MsSdUsS1JSGdGzyo43Vnyn/uIth3cTvP3FbpSKINewdSgAPgYXJUpYruAzuty@Oct4sE0T90o3MVgU4N2PAgmSaMhKkqQgNtxGPjXfBQmxcx4ZNKQKGJYaXqLO52N2WuNYk0t6jeD/uQaZSFD/AA)

```mathematica
f@n_:=Array[Boole[1!=Tr@IntegerDigits[BitAnd[#-1,#2-1],2]]&,2^{n,n}]
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it onlinne!](https://tio.run/##TY5BSwMxEIXv@RVjrk3RFE9rI1WKUEEQ3dswlthu1indicSAwtLfvqa7Hjy94XuPN6/z@aPpfOadH4awkm3lav9@bHATsI7ZH3EjuWmbtOaW8xfec76TPfLcmsPcklkQXThrrLki03PRxZucTH/4u2j4TCz5yefEP9iNsiWoHKwjKoDns4saNSxv4bW40j5GFnzhEMqIOk4MLleQ4rcBDZronNWkyUBp6Ec@NZ8UKfUQEwo4sAYElg6ui85mY3b6JqWm0nRTwP9xAYVI0fAL)

```mathematica
f@n_:=Table[If[Total[IntegerDigits[BitAnd[i-1,j-1],2]]!=1,1,0],{i,1,2^n},{j,1,2^n}]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 65 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(1<<n)].map((_,y,a)=>a.map((_,x)=>(x&=y)&&+!(x&x-1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwEADvvmJ7MbtEQ4XeNELf0ZYSbCyKbiRKUUrfngZpTzNzmd68zNz4blpydg8bWh1Y1xel1Nl7s2FRVUw3NZoJ8Z5tmSFdm3@uMXBN9UZpKg/R1rwgotA6j4NdgEHDsYyo4BQhJcE7AWgcz26wanBPbJFp33nQNXjVu45RgCD66ZUFgYSdZfIJXw)

na